# EJS syntax highlighting in HTML files with Notepad++

Tags: javascript, node.js, notepad++, syntax-highlighting, ejs

I am using Notepad++ to view some HTML files which also have Javascript and EJS (embedded java script, node.js rendering engine) parts. Unfortunately the syntax highlighting often looks like this:

[image]

With EJS you can insert your dynamic stuff like you would do it with PHP in HTML files. The opening tag is **<%** or **<%=** and you close it with **%>**.

Is there any possibility to configure Notepad++ in such a way that syntax highlighting between **<% %>** is ignored? Or that the whole block is treated like normal text or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use ASP syntax highlighting but you will need to use double quote because in ASP ' is a comment.

Hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: In fact, notepad++ already auto-detect EJS as ASP. the screen shot show exacly ASP formatting, precisely with the single quote probleme of being treated as comment.